# SVN and deployments: Keeping sanitary environments

Tags: svn

My team is having problems using SVN to deploy to our QA environment for testing and keeping that DEV stream clean so we can do continued development while QA is going on.

I'm hoping there's some approach out there that will solve our problem that we just haven't come across yet.

Details: We have a DEV branch in SVN and 1 codebase for UI developers and another for server developers.

When we deploy, the .EXE and .SWF files are checked into server-side folder and server developers push to TRUNK. A WAR file is built from there.

The problem is that as QA is going on, server developers continue working on future features and bugs and need to push to QA environment in order to test their code against UI.

We don't have a dedicated DEV environment; we know that's a huge part of the problem.

The question is; do we need to be using another branch in SVN as well for QA? So, every time we push to QA we put code in QA branch?

In this manner, we keep environments sanitary and we can do a build off QA SVN branch whenever we want.

I think, unlike most teams, we don't stop developing when we push to QA. We keep going forward and address the bugs that QA finds as they find them. We push to PROD basically whenever we feel like it. That's why we need a sanitary environment.

Sorry for the long post but we are in a bit of a rut here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this question has much to do with subversion.  It sounds like you've already identified the problem -- you are using a single environment both for DEV testing and QA testing.  You should have two environments for the two functions.

As far as your branching strategy goes, I would recommend you follow a [branch-per-release](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.release) workflow, where you cut a new release branch from the trunk every time you want to do a release to QA, and then to PROD.  You should not be *pushing* code from the trunk to a static QA or PROD branch -- you should cut a *new* branch every time you want to do a release.

Finally, I would recommend that you separate binary/deployable management from your source management.  Don't keep a copy of your latest .exe file in svn right next to the code.  If you want to keep build artifacts in svn, I would recommend setting up your continuous build process to publish the artifacts to a separate svn repository (this process can also publish them to a simple file share, which may be simpler to use).  You want to avoid requiring any manual process to keep your binaries "up to date".

Comment: Thank you for recommending this stragegy; it sounds promising. My only thought is that our process, and it very well could be flawed, is such that I'm back to working on the DEV branch and the QA team comes back with some bugs. Do I make those fixes manually in the QA release branch as well as the DEV branch? Most likely. But doesn't SVN have a tool that facilitates these manual merges?

Comment: You would make the bug fix in one of the branches and merge the change  to the other.  Please read up on subversion's branching and merging functionality (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html).